# Facebook connect: how to add a second domain to the accepted domains for facebook connect

Tags: facebook

I just installed Facebook connect for my Website.

Now I want to make it available for the second domain, my website is accessable with.

Must be possible within the Facebook Settings Page.

How can I do this?

Yours,

Joern.

Answer (score 0):

I created now two Facebook Apps one for each domain. Not the best solution but it works.